# php extract 99 from string regex

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
tomato='36'/></carrot
```

From this I am trying to extract `36` using regex.  I am using:

```
"/tomato='(.*)'\/>/"
```

This extracts the beginning ok, but not the rest.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: You mean you want to extract a attribute from a html element, and it should be `(.*?)`

Comment: Yes it is xml.  But I'm using preg_match rather than dom to practice regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specialize your regex in order to only match numeral characters:

```
"/tomato='(\d+)'\/>/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few tools that can help with constructing regular expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

In your case you might want to match `\d+` decimals rather.

Depending on the actual use case it might be simpler if you didn't use regexps, but a DOM parser[(1)](http://querypath.org) which simplifies the attribute extraction:

```
pq($xml)->find("recipe")->attr("tomato");
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the very specific example you've provided, and the specific data you want to extract, it's fairly simple; your regex can ignore everything except the numeric characters:

```
"/\d+/"
```

If the input string could vary, and you specifically want to find the value of the `tomato` attribute, then:

```
"/tomato='(\d+)'/"
```

There's unlikely to be any real need to be matching the rest of the string - in fact, it's more likely to cause problems, given how variable XML can be.

But the question is, what exactly are you trying to do here? It looks very much like you're trying to parse an HTML/XML stream, but how did you end up with just this odd chunk? Did you do `explode(' ',$xml);`?

You may find a more scalable and manageable way of extracting data from an XML stream would be to use a DOM parser instead. Regex can work, but HTML/XML tends to have sufficient variation in formatting that you end up with some really really horrible regex strings if you want to be certain of getting the data you want; a DOM parser tends to be much more reliable in this respect.

May I suggest you investigate PHP's built-in DOM parser: http://www.php.net/dom

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is interesting and I will read further, but since I used the other guys answer I have to accept his.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try matching up to the first quote, and then grabbing everything that isn't a quote character:

```
/tomato='([^']*)'/
```

This method works well if you have no clue about what will be between the quotes, however it fails if the final quote is missing, or if you use double quotes instead of single quotes.